# How to put object in hidden input field using html and cheeypy

Tags: python, html, cherrypy

```
    below is abc.html

    <div xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" py:strip="True" >
            <div class="insync-bluthm-tbl-wrp">
                <div class="insync-bluthm-tbl-scroll">
                    <div class="insync-bluthm-tbl-scroll-inr">
                        <table class="insync-bluthm-tbl">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><div>File Name</div></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <input type="hidden" id="restorable_data" value="${restoreData}"/>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div>Dummy File name</div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    below is python function

    @cherrypy.expose
    def can_restore_mds(self, *args, **kwargs):
    restoreData = {
            'abc': 'def',
            'akjshd': 'asd',
            'is_valid': 1,
    }
    restore_context = {
        'page': 'abc.html',
        'restoreData': restoreData,
    }
    html = render_page(restore_context, restore_context['page'])
    return {
        'html': html,
        'restoreData': restoreData,
    }
    return response
```

"restoreData" is variable which is not getting injected in proper format in server-side rendering can anyone please help what needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use json dumps function to do this:-

Python

```
# remember to import json in your python file
restoreData = {
    'abc': 'def',
    'akjshd': 'asd',
    'is_valid': 1,
}
restore_context = {
    'page': 'abc.html',
    'restoreData': json.dumps(restoreData),
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="restorable_data" value="${restoreData}"/>
```